# Wish To Modify A Javascript Button Color

Tags: javascript

A vendor (Payhip) has embed code for a "buy product now" button on a website page that activates a popup to buy the product without leaving the site. I want to modify the "buy now" button color. As this is the vendor's code and tied to their site, I'm not sure this is even possible.

I created a button in color I want, added the vendor's link code, but it sends user off the client's site, which I want to avoid. I've tried:

1. adding a new class for "data-theme";
2. placing the product link inside code I created for a red button;
3. tried removing the data-theme code, but it defaults to green
4. tried change data-theme="#color:#ff0000"
5. added a var to the javascript code, which I didn't think would work, and I was correct.

I'm usually able to find code for something similar to what I want to do when it comes code to modify and implement for my use, but I'm completely baffled at the moment.

I'm not even sure this is possible since it's Payhip's code and not mine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://payhip.com/payhip.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var PayhipConfig = {
    enableCart: true
};
 </script>

<a href="https://payhip.com/b/8NUp" class="payhip-add-to-cart-button" data-theme="grey" data-product="8NUp">Buy Now</a>
```

I want to have a red buy now button that when clicked opens the shopping cart. Any assistance is greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Did you try setting the color via `buttonEl.style.backgroundColor = color`?

Comment: This should be tagged with payhip.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like that before and my solution was set data-theme="none" and created my own style.

[https://payhip.com/support/embed-buttons/]

Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

There are several different approaches you could take.

I couldn't find any examples of how to use data-theme.

https://payhip.com/support/embed-buttons/

On this page they describe how you could make your own button and give it JavaScript starts checkout. You would do this rather than using the  and having Payhip's JavaScript turn it into a button that initiates checkout on click. Then you could style the button with whatever CSS classes you want.

It really depends on how comfortable you are at writing JavaScript, CSS, and HTML.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I looked at that code a couple of weeks ago and got squeamish. :D I do fine with CSS and HTML, but javascript is a bit out of my league. But after learning some javascript today, I might take another stab at that. Thanks for reminding me of that snippet.